# SML functional programming higher order function?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, higher-order-functions

I need to implement a function

```
 ziprev : 'a list -> 'b list -> ('a * 'b) list
 - ziprev [1,2,3,4] [10,20,30,40];
 val it = [(1,40),(2,30),(3,20),(4,10)] : (int * int) list
```

Using a function that I already created:

```
- zipW (fn (x, y) => x + y) [1,2,3,4] [10,20,30,40];
val it = [11,22,33,44] : int list
```

and the List.rev from the library. 
I have no idea how to do a function with two libraries. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint 1:**

Compare the result of your `ziprev` with

```
List.zip [1,2,3,4] [10,20,30,40]
```

You should see a fairly obvious pattern.

**Hint 2:**

`List.rev` *reverses* a list.

**Hint 3:**

Can you use `zipW` to implement `List.zip`?
That is, if you want to say

```
normalzip xs ys = zipW something xs ys
```

what would `something` be?